# Summations of Legendre Symbols with an odd prime p

Tags: number-theory, summation, legendre-symbol

Let $p$ be an odd prime. For any integer $k$, define $S(k,p) = \sum^{p}_{x=1}(\frac{x(x+k)}{p})$.

(i) Show that S(0,$p$) = $p$-1

(ii) Show that if p does not divide k then $S(k,p) = S(1,p)$

(iii) Conclude that if p does not divide k then $S(k,p) = -1$

Been struggling with this question for a couple of days with no progress.

Comment: I have looked through the other question you suggested but it does not answer question (i) for me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it is in the duplicate "Show that: (i)  $s(0, p) = p − 1$". This is obvious since $(n^2/p)=(n/p)^2=1$.